# Big GC pause caused by Kafka producer in microservice

Tags: java, performance, apache-kafka, garbage-collection, kafka-producer-api

One of my web services sends log message (size: 10K) to kafka (version: 0.10.2.1) for each online request, and I found that the KafkaProducer consumes lots of memory which caused long gc pausing time.
There is only one Kafka producer in my service, which is recommended officially.

I am just wondering if anyone has any suggestions on how to send messages to kafka without any impact on the online services?

Comment: what java-version,  what memory settings, where is the log, what GC have you used, how you _know_ about the pauses?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the producer isn't able to keep up with the rate at which your service is generating logs. (This is necessarily speculation since you have given minimal details about your setup).

Have you benchmarked your kafka cluster? Is it able to sustain the kind of load you generate?

Another avenue would be to decouple your kafka producer from your actual service. Since you're dealing with log messages, your application can simply write the logs to disk, and you can have a separate process reading these log files and sending them to kafka. This way the producing of messages won't impact your main service.

You can even have the kafka producer running on a different VM/Container entirely, and read the logs via something like an NFS mount.